# Assocative array loop only prints first 2 characters

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to access a value from an associative array, but the loop is only printing first 2 characters from the first element.

```
<?php

 $memServer = array(

        array("IPSSSSS" , "Port")  //I want to print the first element 



);


for($i = 0; $i< count($memServer); $i++)
{
for($j = 0; $j<count($memServer[$i]); $j++)
{

    echo $memServer[$i][$j][0];
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry man :( My code is not working ...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not an associative array. An example of an associative array would be `array('key' => 'value')`.

The loop is **not** printing the the first 2 characters of the first element; it is printing the first character (I) of "IPSSSSS" and the first character (P) of "Port".

You must get rid of the inner for loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i< count($memServer); $i++)
{
    //for($j = 0; $j<count($memServer[$i]); $j++)
    //{
    echo $memServer[$i][0];
    //}
}
```

(or use a `foreach` construction as described by John Conde).

Comment: The coded you provided was working .. But when i try to access the element .. It's throwing array to string conversion warning